# Can you give an example of an n-bit constant function for the Deutsch-Joza algorithm?

Tags: oracles, deutsch-jozsa-algorithm

I was studying the implementation of DJ algorithm using Qiskit. I designed an oracle circuit for a balanced function and verified the output. Now I want to do the same for a constant function. Unfortunately, I cannot design an oracle circuit for a constant function. Please help.

Comment: Edit your question to provide details of what you've done and where you are confused.  Thanks!

Comment: I was studying the DJ algorithm implementation. I designed an oracle circuit for a balanced function and verified the output. Now I want to do the same for a constant function. Unfortunately, I cannot design an oracle circuit for a  constant function.

Comment: Please edit your question to include this information.  Click the "Edit" button next to the "Share" button.  Also, edit your posting to explain what software you were using to design your oracle.

Answer (score 1):

To implement constant function $f(x)=0$, an oracle contains no gate, or equivalently put an identity operator on ancilla qubit in the oracle.

For function $f(x)=1$, put $X$ gate on the ancilla. No other gate is needed.

Note that the implementation above is independent of number of qubits involved.